# iOS simulator build for Facebook app approval crashes

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, ios-simulator

I have done everything specified by Facebook. I even validated the sim build using the ios-sim tools and it runs fine on my Mac. There are no crashes. Has anyone had this problem before? What am I missing. here is a screenshot :
[image]

Edit I gave it another try and I got the same results. Even for the Android build. I was thinking tht maybe i sent them a zip by mistake but this time I double checked that I'm sending them a link to a .apk file to download from Mega.nz. Testing the iOS sim build on my end yields nothing since the game runs fine. I'm in dire need of some sage advice from someone who has gone trough this process. Here is another screenshot from todays rejection. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case I just set the app in facebook to be active for the public. This allowed my users to log in and share post, from the app to facebook. I'm Only missing the publish_actions permission. Just get your app approved on the app store and send facebook the link for that. Simulation builds just dont work for them

Answer (score 1):

Dude I never tried it before but I read somewhere that if you are getting trouble to get approved by selecting iOS on submitting you can select Android as platform on submission and after approved your facebook integrations will be working fine for iOS apps too.

Doesn't cost too much to have a try ;)

Comment: after googling for a while I came to the same conclusion, but I now I face the problem with the 3 day ban from submitting. I wonder if deleting the whole app and starting again will fix this or maybe the ban is tied to my account.